# Override the overflow: hidden style

Tags: css, react-virtualized

Is it possible to override the overflow: hidden style in a table?  I would like to have a button on each row that opens a dropdown.  However, the dropdown is currently hidden because it overflows the row.

In the Chrome developer tools, I can see the dropdown if I manually remove overflow:hidden from .ReactVirtualized__Table__row and .ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn.  However, I have not found a way to do this with either javascript or css.

So far I've tried:

Adding overflow: visible to the ReactVirtualized classes. I tried this in both the original styles.css file and in a separate included css file.

```
.ReactVirtualized__Grid{
    overflow: visible;
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__Grid {
    overflow: visible;
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__row {
    overflow: visible;
}
.ReactVirtualized__Table__rowColumn {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Adding the rowStyle and Style props to Reactvirtualized.Table:

```
<ReactVirtualized.AutoSizer>
  {({height, width}) => (
    <ReactVirtualized.Table
      width={width}
      height={height}
      headerHeight={35}
      rowHeight={(height - 35) / 5}
      rowCount={content.length}
      rowGetter={({index}) => content[index]}
      rowClassName="al-table-view__row"
      headerClassName="al-table-view__header"
      rowStyle={{overflowY: 'visible'}}
      style={{overflowY: 'visible'}}
    >
      {this.getColumns(width)}
    </ReactVirtualized.Table>
  )}
</ReactVirtualized.AutoSizer>
```

I've been able to add my own classes and style them, but I have not been able to override the overflow style there either.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the `overflow` style isn't the right answer. Even if you overflow a single row, your dropdown wouldn't overflow the boundaries of the `Table` itself and so the lower rows would have the same problem.

For this sort of thing- I suggest you check out [`react-portal`](https://github.com/tajo/react-portal). Portals lift content out of the z-index stack (and so avoid clipping problems) while maintaining the visual position of it (top/left), allowing it to render outside of the clipping rect/box of its parent. They're perfect for things like drop-down menus within `List` or `Table`.

Comment: Can you please point any example of how make content of a cell "overflow" `react-portal`?